# Using chrome extension in incognito mode

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am developing a chrome extension with Manifest version 3 and due to bug https://crbug.com/1271154, the service worker broken once you reload or allow it work in incognito mode. Is there any quick fix that I may run my extension properly in incognito mode?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.